# Reset the REINSTALL and REINSTALLMODE flags for major upgrade

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.7

I have an NSIS script that uses the command line:

`msiexec.exe /i installer.msi REINSTALL=ALL REINSTALLMODE=vdmus`

The msi is built using Wix. This works fine for minor upgrades, but fail for major upgrade.

So I want to know if there is a way in Wix to **reset** the `REINSTALL` and `REINSTALLMODE` flags once we detect that we are doing a major upgrade?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A major upgrade doesn't use REINSTALL or REINSTALLMODE. An MSI built for a minor upgrade has the same ProductCode as the one it's updating (among other things) and an MSI built for a major upgrade does not have the same ProductCode. Therefore to do a major upgrade you just launch the MSI in the "normal" way, and for a minor upgrade you launch an MSI file with REINSTALL and REINSTALLMODE. You need two separate command lines, and use the appropriate one when you know what kind of install you're doing. That is the safest and maybe only thing to do.

BTW, this is nothing to do with WiX - it's true whatever tool you use to build an MSI file.

Comment: Thanks for your response, you suggest two separate command lines, but there is no way to distinguish between major upgrade and minor upgrade in NSIS. Therefore I was wondering if there was a way of resetting these falgs in Wix.

Comment: Your post says "once we detect that we are doing a major upgrade?" and sounds like you already knew how to detect a major upgrade. If you don't, there isn't an msiexec command line that will work for both scenarios. The usual way that people detect whether it's a minor or major upgrade before a launch is by 1) Knowing the ProductCode and UpgradeCode of the MSI you want to install 2) Calling MsiEnumRelatedComponents (....UpgradeCode....) and if you get back a ProductCode that is the same as the one you're installing it's a minor upgrade. If different, a major upgrade.

Comment: The command line for MSIEXEC actually is overriding the directives set up by Wix in the MSI.